# Display XSLT variable in different colors depending on condition

Tags: jquery, xslt, colors

I have an xslt file. In this file, I have an xsl choose statement. When certain conditions occur (for example, when the variable is either positive or negative), I want to display that xsl variable in a different color. I know how to set up the choose statement - my problem is being able to set the color to display it in. I've been told to use a JQuery .addClass() function, but I have no idea how to do this. Any information at how to do this, and if I need to import anything into my file to do so would be great. thanks!

Comment: can you provide any code snippet so we can help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [CSS can be used to style an XML document](http://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/xml_css.cfm), there is no need to use jQuery here (in my opinion).

Here is how I would approach the problem. When your XSLT produces elements based on `choose`, simply assign an attribute `class` and a value `positive` or `negative`) to the element that you output (`number`), so you have the output like:

```
<number class="positive">5</number>
<number class="negative">-5</number>
```

The CSS selector can then look like:

```
number.positive { color: blue; }
number.negative { color: red; }
```

Comment: does the number.positive need to be surrounded by anything? like showing that it is css?

Comment: No, it does not have to be. CSS has a different syntax than XML (a [tutorial](http://www.csstutorial.net)). XML describes the data, CSS describes how to present it.